# Why dharmic religions are not organized?

Tags: history, philosophy

Why dharmic religions like Hinduism, Buddhism etc. are not organized whereas [Abrahamic religions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abrahamic_religions) (Islam, Christianity) are organized? For example, Islam has its mosques which dictate the way of life, dress code etc. whereas Christianity has its churches. But I don't know any such thing in Hinduism.

Comment: Hinduism is organized; there are Shankaracharyas in Advaita, Jeeyars in Sri Vaishnavism, etc. And those religious leaders do provide instructions concerning how one should live one's life.  Now not every Hindu follows such a figure, but generally Hindus are at least supposed to go to a guru and follow his instructions.  So I don't see what distinction you're making.

Comment: agree with @KeshavSrinivasan

Comment: What do you mean by dharmic religions?

Comment: What do you mean organized? All the abhrahamic sects quarrel with each other and do not recognize the legitimacy of each other. There is no overreaching authority over all of them nor even among all Islamists or all Christians. If they are organized I would hate to see disorganization...

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, Not every Advaitin is supposed to follow Shankaracarya, not so sure about Sri Vaishnavam. On the contrary, every Catholic is supposed to treat the Pope as hand of God on Earth. That's the distinction. [http://www.churchauthority.org/blueprint/pope.asp]

Comment: @Yogi, Dharmic religion is a term coined by Rajiv Malhtora, AFAIK. Dharmic traditions are those which originated in India and the law of Dharma/Karma plays an important role in their theology. All Indic religion (since they all originated from Hinduism and hence are Dharma oriented) come under it.

Comment: @VineetMenon Well, the Catholic Church is defined to be those churches which are in communion with the Bishop of Rome, so yes by definition if your church is Catholic then you believe the Pope is the Vicar of Christ.  But that's exactly analogous to Hinduism: if your family or your guru (for converts) is affiliated with the Kanchi Shankaracharya, then so will you.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, Ok. Let me rephrase my conjecture a bit. There cannot be a RC without affirming his belief in Roman Pope, but there can be an Advaitin who doesn't follow Sankaracarya. At least, I'm one. :)

Comment: @VineetMenon I think the problem is that you're conflating affiliation and ideology.  All Iyers (I think) follow the Kanchi Shankaracharya, just as all Catholics follow the Pope.  On the other hand, not all Advaitins follow the Kanchi Shankaracharya, and not everyone who believes in the Trinity follow the Pope.

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan, 'Iyer' is a *jati*, not a religious sect/denomination while Advaitin is one. The word a person who 'believes in Trinity' is Christian not Catholic. Being Catholic is a subset of being Christian.

Comment: @VineetMenon First of all, not all Christians believe in the Trinity. But my point is that if you look at a belief like belief in the Trinity or belief in the divinity of Mary, it wouldn't be true that everyone who holds these beliefs are loyal to the Pope. And if you look at Protestant sects, there is no central figure like that. Also, it should be noted that the presence of significant numbers of Advaitins who don't align themselves with any Shankaracharyas is a recent phenomenon, due to propagation of Advaita through means other than Parampara. But it's not true of sects other than Advaita.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about Hindu Dharma not being organized (not so sure about Buddha Dharma). The reason seems to me is due to the fact that dharmas are for seekers of Truth while Abrahamic faiths are for believers. Believers in Abrahamic faiths need to know exactly what they should do in every sphere of life since these faiths do not encourage seeking but ask for unquestioned belief.

Answer (score 0):

I think its difficult to compare Hinduism with other religion like Islam and Christianity, because these both are religion which follows similar kind of philosophy. While Hinduism is inherited from Aryan or Vaidic culture, Which involves variety of philosophy and belief out of which widely accepted philosophy are included in Vedas. In Hinduism there is freedom of thoughts and believes and also scope for new philosophy and scriptures.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism SE! You should cite sources for your answer.

Comment: @AnilKumar I didnt add any source and reference because I have written this from the general understanding of indian culture.

Comment: Answers on this site should be backed up with references. Else you can post your answer as comment under the question.